# Why can't I execute "bundle exec rake secret"? The error “bad interpreter: No such file or directory” occured

Tags: command-line, bash, homebrew, vi, rails

My ruby ​​version is 2.7.3, my mysql version is 8.0.23, my mysql2 version is 0.5.3, my rails version is 5.0.7.2, and my Xcode version is 12.5.

I use macOS Big Sur(version 11.4) and the text editor "Atom".

I'm planning to release my Rails application with the URL of HEROKU(example. https://[My APP Name].herokuapp.com).

I ran the following command.

```
$ heroku open
```

The following error occured.

```
An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.
```

I ran the following command.

```
$ heroku logs

#<RuntimeError: Missing
 `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `
config/secrets.yml`>
```

My `config/secrets.yml` file is something like belows.

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

I edited my `config/secrets.yml` file as below.

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["secret_key_base"] %>
```

I deleted two environment variables as below with this command: `$ heroku config:unset [ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE NAME]`.

```
$ heroku config:unset DATABASE_USERNAME=****
```

```
$ heroku config:unset DATABASE_PASSWORD=GENERATED_CODE
```

I deleted the environment variable `SECRET_KEY_BASE` in the vim editor of `/etc/profile` , using the following command.

```
$ vi /etc/profile
```

I saved the vim editor of `/etc/profile` to end it with the two below commands.

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

```
:q!
```

I deleted the environment variable `SECRET_KEY_BASE`, using the following command.

```
$ vi ~/.bash_profile
```

I saved `.bash_profile` ,using <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then `":x"` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I ran the following command.

```
$ bundle exec rake secret

bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/
usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I ran the following command.

```
$ sed -i 's/\r//' usr/local/bin/bundle

sed: 1: "usr/local/bin/bundle": invalid command code u
```

I ran the following command.

```
$ /usr/local/bin/bundle

bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/
usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Below are the output of `gem env`, `which bundle` and `which ruby`.

```
$ gem env

RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.3 (2019-04-16 patchlevel 62) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/****/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/
ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin

  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/****/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-20
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
     - /Users/****/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.
0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Users/****/.rbenv/shims
```

```
$ which bundle

/usr/local/bin/bundle
```

```
$ which ruby

/usr/bin/ruby
```

Why can't I execute `bundle exec rake secret`? The error `bad interpreter: No such file or directory` occured.

Comment: `bundle` seems to call 2.3, the other output indicates that you have 2.6 installed. What does `ls -l /usr/bin/ruby` return, what `head -1 /usr/local/bin/bundle`?

Comment: Should I install the ruby version '2.3'? Because there were the following messages.                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                               `$ /usr/local/bin/bundle

bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/
usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: Please start with answering the points raised in the previous comment.